# Was bedeutet Thée auf Deutsch?

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english, history

What is the meaning of the word Thée in the attached picture?  Is it German?

[image]

Here is whole photo and in context of book.

[image]

Here is the cover of the book from where the above photos were taken:

[image]

Comment: The only real German word in the picture is "und" ;)

Comment: I am not a native German speaker and even the dialects of the today are cryptically hard for me to understand, but I think it one doesn't need to be an archeological linguest to understand: "cafee und thée" means "cofee and tee" here...

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thée

Comment: Are they just older spellings of words in German?  Or  Germans appropriating French spelling in German sentence?

Comment: At that time, French was a lingua franca across Europe (for those parts of society who could afford it). The ordinary countryman and trades person would have spoken some variety of German. Nobilty and rich bourgois (!) would often communicate in French, particularly so in writing.

Comment: @JonathanMuse Could you please edit your post and add the source of your picture?

Comment: What you see is a mid-18th century European starbucks (kind of).

Comment: I erred on the tim: that copper engraving is said to be from mid 17th century Germany (not mit 18th).

Comment: @Marzipanherz I’m still working on this. It’s out of a book at my in-laws house, and I will be there Christmas. The book is called “how to make coffee” or something.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not until recently (in language history terms) the German spelling of tea indeed was

> Thee

It is listed in [old dictionaries](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GT03168#XGT03168), and was use by Goethe and Schiller too. The accent was unusual even then and may have come from the artist's inspiration.

Comment: I doubt that the accent on the last e in *cafeé* has ever been common either.

Comment: @jarnbjo: da bin ich völlig deiner Meinung :)

Comment: To get an idea of *until recently*: in the 1894/1896 [Brockhaus](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/schlagwort.html?wort=Thee&werk=brockhaus)  *Thee* was still the correct spelling.

Answer (score 8):

It's *tea*, in an old-fashioned spelling. Nowadays it would be *der Tee*. The acute accent suggests the spelling is French.

Comment: We still write "thee" in Dutch (but without "accent aigu").

Answer (score 4):

The clothing style suggests that this picture was drawn way more than 100 years ago. At the time, it was overwhelmingly common for German to be written in blackletter typefaces but other languages, especially Latin, were written in antiqua typefaces. The picture nicely displays both: note how the letter style of the *und* is completely different from that in *Cafeé, Thée* and *Logia*. The first is written in blackletter while the others are in antiqua.

This already tells us that the author considered all words except *und* to be inherently non-German. (While typographic standards were probably not as strict then as they are now this is the most logical way to explain the two styles.) Furthermore, an accent is not an original German diacritic which further strengthens the case of *Cafeé* and *Thée* being considered foreign.

They were probably considered French (on the balance of probabilities) even though the accent placement in *Cafeé* is one I never came across and I am unsure whether it ever was correct in French.

Comment: .....more than 200 years....

Comment: @fdb 200 > 100, also passt?

Comment: Der erste Duden erschien aber vor über und weniger als 200 Jahren, daher ist diese Feststellung durchaus bedeutsam. > 1000 Jahre wäre auch > 100, aber "at that time" passt dann nicht mehr. Von wann bis wann war denn Antiqua für Latein üblich - Du kennst Dich da ja scheinbar aus?

Answer (score 2):

Well, Jonathan, your question "Is it German?" can be answered with YES when it's about intelligibility, communicativeness,  and conventions from quite some time ago, and it must be NO when it's about today's spelling rules.

The "picture" shows both renaissance and baroque elements. They are conspicuous. We may thus suppose early to mid 17th century. Christian G.'s " from mid 17th century" is therefore either close or right.

In **Chri­stoph Adelung. Grammatisch-kritisches Wörterbuch der Hochdeutschen Mundart** (1774-86), the principle still was: "Schrei­be, wie du sprichst." (Write as you talk). This is what the 'artist' did about 150 years earlier.

*Rechtschreibung* (German spelling rules) as we apply it today is the invention of a school teacher, Konrad Duden. The first 'Duden' was published in 1880. It is consequently a severe misconception when David R. talks about "spell[ing] every word wrong except the und" in a picture that's about 250 years older.

As to the artist's way of spelling: He evidently somehow knew the pronunciation and spelling of French *café* and *thé*, and in a - what we now call - 'creative process', free of any spelling rules, wrote *cafeé* and *thée*, a mixture of French and phonetic spelling. Today's Swedish uses the same principle for the spelling of borrowed French words. The 'artist's' *LOGIA* rather seems to imitate Italian, but I can't say more as I do not know how *loggia* was or could be spelled centuries ago.

All of this leads us to a YES and a NO with equal rights.

Comment: This is mainly a comment to another post, which might get edited or deleted, rendering this one useless. Better you split the part, which might count as an answer, and post the rest as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the artist got confused but there is some basis for this confusion. Firstly these were exotic novelties so no one would be sure of spelling, pronunciation or gender.

Secondly German ee and French é are pronounced very roughly the same so these could be hybrids. To put it another way the second e would help a German pronounce them even if they did not understand the use of accents in French.

Thirdly the second e in French makes these words look more feminine so these spellings might be seen plausible if the gender had not been agreed (in either French or German).

But the eé shows a lack of knowledge of French so my best guess is that the artist simply spelt them in German as Cafee and Thee (before the spellings of these words had been standardized and before th had been replaced by t and c by k) and that they added the accents to make them look more French or at least more foreign - for all we know it is an attempt at Italian as Italian has accents and Loggia is usually regarded as Italian. We also know the spelling is not very good as [Loggia](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loggia) has double g in Italian, French, German and English.

Comment: The artist definitely was not confused. He just used French words that were totally common in the respective parts of society - namely those who could afford  novelty luxury goods: tea and coffee.

Comment: He was confused, @christiangeiselmann, because he managed to spell every word wrong except the und.

Comment: @David: indeed. The French words would have been *café* and *thé*.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Is your claim based on deep knowledge of the various spelling habits of French in 18 century central Europe? Or rather on ignorance of them? You will probably agree that French spelling in the 21st century might differ from French spelling in the 18th century? (A score for you, however, as I have to admit: the placement of the accent on the first than second é indeed looks less regular then expected.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I have done enough general reading of French, including C18 French to recognize a bizarre spelling when I see one. ée only occurs in feminine participles and words that originally had two separate vowels (e.g. athée - atheist).  In addition, several other people who have responded here have failed to find these spellings. To be on the safe side, La 4e édition (1762) du Dictionnaire de l'Académie française gives [café](https://academie.atilf.fr/4/consulter/CAFÉ?options=motExact&page=1) and thé but not cafée, cafeé or thée.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann However when I looked in the most modern one under [café](https://academie.atilf.fr/9/consulter/caf%C3%A9?page=1) I found: *CAFÉ n. m. xviie siècle, d'abord cauueh, cafeh. Emprunté, sans doute par l'intermédiaire de l'italien caveé, caffé, du turc qahve, lui-même de l'arabe qahwa.* This is very interesting as it gives the early Italian form as caveé. This is not a modern spelling and I know nothing about C18 Italian spelling but it does suggest that cafeé could be an intermediate between caveé and the modern caffè.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I have found no evidence for thée in Italian but I have found that [tè comes from French thé](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t%C3%A8#Italian) which may explain why it sometimes spelt [thè](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C3%A8). It may well have been spelt as in French when first borrowed. This means that overall we can say that the whole text is closer to the Italian than to the French.

Comment: @DavidRobinson So would you entertain the hypothesis that the artist actually wanted to create Italian text?

Comment: @DavidRobinson  Thanks for the details! - My argument is that the artist simply rendered what in his time and place was common use, e.g. visible on shop signs etc. He did not care for spelling traditions of a specific language. The words written on such signs may in practice have been spelled who knows how, not different from today where you find German cities plastered with signs "SALE" (a non-German word, not in use elsewhere but on shops), and you find all kinds of silly spellings such as misplaced apostrophs and so on. Showing this in a picture does not mean that the artist is "confused".

Comment: @Jan I am certainly suggesting  it seems more Italian than French, as the Log(g)ia is from Italian, the eé can only be explained by Italian and the French word thé was used in Italian. I have found that the word tea is so complicated that Wikipedia has a whole article on [Etymologie des Begriffs Tee](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymologie_des_Begriffs_Tee).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann We now have four possibilities: (1) the artist  got confused, (2) that the sign-writer got confused. They are often not very good at foreign accents. I have seen 'Les Âmis du Vin' though it did get changed, and in Scotland, Fáilte (Irish for Welcome) is more common than Fàilte (Scots Gaelic for Welcome). You see it all over the place but I did once see Fäilte. Or (3) society was confused, or (4) the artist was mocking the class of people who go to 'Logias' to drink novelties like cafeé and thée. Perhaps the und was mocking their lack of knowledge of Italian and French.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann I have posted a related question on [the Italian SE](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10110/is-cafe%C3%A9-und-th%C3%A9e-logia-partly-italian).

Comment: @DavidRobinson  I vote for (4) - artist mocking the hipsters of his time (or whoever frequented such fancy places where thée and cafeé were served). I would suppose he also mocked them for their liberal mixing of words from various European languages (here: French, German, Italian). Und heureka: touché, amigo!

Comment: Im 17. und 18. Jhr. war Französisch die Lingua Franca an europäischen Höfen, was aus laienhafter Sicht mit der Kleidung (Baguettes als Hüte, *hust*) korrespondiert. In Deutschland kam der erste Duden erst wesentlich später (Ende 19. Jhr.) raus - davor gab es keine falschen Schreibweisen. Was das Geschlecht der Wörter hier zu suchen hat erschließt sich mir nicht. Auch weiß hier niemand, ob der Grafiker die Bechriftung erfunden oder in einer Szene abgezeichnet hat. Logia mit einem G findet sich übrigens im Spanischen.